# My Android studio maked app is not install into other device. It's only work in debugged device. What can I do?

Tags: android-studio, apk

When I make any apps with the android studio it's worked when I build it in my device but when I share this app from my device to any other device than that app is not installed. It shows a message that "App is not installed" what can I do now! how can I get rid from this problem? Please help me.

Comment: please generate an apk from Android Studio IDE and share that apk file to others..

Comment: @Murad theOZ do just as Vijaya said, and don't forget to tell those device to enable install from unknown source.

Comment: thanks for your Answer guys. that's really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate signed apk file from Android Studio. Apk file which was build in your debugging device, won't run on any other device.

- Android Studio toolbar, go to Build → Generate Signed APK.
- On the Generate Signed APK Wizard window, click Create new to create a new keystore.
- On the New Key Store window, provide the required information
- On the Generate Signed APK Wizard window, select a keystore (if existing), a private key, and enter the passwords for both.
- On the next window, select a destination path for the signed APK and click Finish.